# ldapadd, slapadd, ldapmodify hang when trying to add entries

Tags: ldap, solaris, openldap

I have recently installed OpenLDAP on Solaris-10.  Whether using
slapadd, ldapadd, or ldapmodify, I am able to establish the root node
and the child, but when I try to add an entry for a person under
inetorgperson, the command hangs.  Here is my current slapd.conf file:

```
include  /usr/local/etc/openldap/schema/core.schema
include  /usr/local/etc/openldap/schema/cosine.schema
include  /usr/local/etc/openldap/schema/inetorgperson.schema

pidfile  /usr/local/var/run/slapd.pid
argsfile /usr/local/var/run/slapd.args

loglevel -1

#######################################################################
# BDB database definitions
#######################################################################

database        bdb
suffix          "dc=myorg,dc=org"
rootdn          "cn=Manager,dc=myorg,dc=org"

rootpw          secret

directory       /usr/local/var/myorg.org

index   objectClass             eq
index   cn,sn,mail              eq,sub
index   departmentNumber        eq

cachesize 10000
checkpoint 128 15
```

Here is the .ldif file I am currently trying to use:

```
dn: dc=myorg,dc=org
dc: myorg
objectClass: dcObject
objectClass: organizationalUnit
ou: Myorg Dot Org

dn: ou=people,dc=myorg,dc=org
ou:people
objectClass: organizationalUnit

dn: cn=Jerry Carter,ou=people,dc=myorg,dc=org
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
cn: Jerry Carter
sn: Carter
```

Here is the ldap command I have most recently tried:

```
ldapadd -x -v -d -1 -D "cn=Manager,dc=myorg,dc=org" \
    -f /ldif/top.ldif -w secret
```

The first two entries from the .ldif file are successful, but the last
one hangs. The following messages appear repeating in a loop:

```
** ld 805b7d0 Outstanding Requests:
 * msgid 2,  origid 2, status InProgress
   outstanding referrals 0, parent count 0
  ld 805b7d0 request count 1 (abandoned 0)
** ld 805b7d0 Response Queue:
   Empty
  ld 805b7d0 response count 0
ldap_chkResponseList ld 805b7d0 msgid 2 all 1
ldap_chkResponseList returns ld 805b7d0 NULL
ldap_int_select
ldap_result ld 805b7d0 msgid 2
wait4msg ld 805b7d0 msgid 2 (timeout 100000 usec)
wait4msg continue ld 805b7d0 msgid 2 all 1
** ld 805b7d0 Connections:
* host: localhost  port: 389  (default)
  refcnt: 2  status: Connected
  last used: Wed Jan 19 12:21:51 2011
```

Comment: Have you loaded the inetOrgPerson schema into the ldap server?

Comment: in your ldif file, do you have a newline after "sn: Carter" ?

Answer (score 1):

Your LDAP databases may have become corrupt.

Try recovering by doing the following:

- stop openldap
- copy the entire folder someplace safe
- do a slapcat
- delete the database files
- run slapadd